# Combining Hdmi video with composite audii

Tags: hdmi

I have a setup with a videocamera in a chapel and an audio amplifier. The output of the camera is HDMI. The output of the audio is composite (red and White).

Next I have streamer with HDMI input that streams that input over the network to a headend.

Inbetween those two the camera hdmi output needs to be combined with the audio into one hdmi output.

With what hardware can this be done (low cost)? Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Premium-HDMI-DVI-Audio-Combiner-With-HDMI-Repeater-Function-/311215250396